# Classic Menu went belly up. the Icon is on upper right hand side, it shows the headings, but it no longer expands to the show actual applications

Tags: appmenu

I run Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.  ClassicMenu was originally installed by me from "Ubuntu Software" icon 10 years ago.  It has worked fine for years.  The main menu was getting clogged up, so I attempted to modify using ClassicMenu Indicator to cut down # of menus items (replicas).  There was some duplication and I adjusted the menutypes (apparently that was a mistake).
None of the actual applications display now, only the headings.  I tried uninstall/re-install, but no change...only application headings, but no application list each underheading.
I tried to follow a solution I found under google search within Ubuntu.com, No Joy.
I am looking for recommendations.
FYI, while I had ClassicMenu working it did not look as graphic as it was represented in the solution I found.

Comment: I assume you have no backup?